# How to enable Arabic keyboard in Peppermint OS 7?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, xfce, keyboard-layout, xubuntu

My friend just installed Peppermint 7 (based on Ubuntu 16.04, with xfce) on his laptop. Arabic is installed on the system, he's trying to use the Saudi Arabian version.

I'd like to leave the language as English but be able to switch the keyboard to arabic.

Xfce keyboard switcher doesn't seem to be working, doesn't detect arabic, right clicking it and trying to select its settings won't work either.

Arabic option is grayed in keyboard layout

`sudo echo '@setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle "us,ar"' | sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/lxsession/Peppermint/autostart`

and

`sudo echo '@setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle "en,ar"' | sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/lxsession/Peppermint/autostart`

Doesn't seem to work either. Personally I have never installed a secondary language on my PC and the solutions I tried are the ones posted on peppermint's forum. I don't know what else to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by following instructions from [here](https://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php/topic,4810.0.html)

Basically it seems that I needed to install this

https://launchpad.net/~peppermintos/+archive/ubuntu/p7-dev/+files/xfce4-settings_4.12.0-2ubuntu1+peppermint1_amd64.deb

Since the guy on the forum claims that the newer versions won't work. After doing that I was able to add arabic

> Click the Add button (+) .. highlight the "Keyboard Layouts" item, and
>   click the "Add" button. (You'll see a flag appear by your clock) click
>   the "Close button.

And I had to restart the PC. Perhaps a log out / log in would work but I did a restart.